I recently update my android studio and now I cannot open the emulator
I tried to reinstall the emulator but reach the same result most of time a message comes "Connecting to emulator" and if it open display a black screen like this
enter image description here
environment

Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 1
Android API 35
Emulator 34.2.16

reinstall emulator
change the device
